# Android TextView Width units?

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to retrieve the width of my TextView which is loaded with text. Here is the code I use,

```
txt_MyText.measure(0, 0);
float textViewWidth = txt_MyText.getMeasuredWidth();
```

> Now this code returns the value as 25882.0
>
> I am testing this on Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge which has a Screen
>   Dimension of Samsung Galaxy S6, S6 Edge   5.1″    1440×2560

I am not sure in what unit this value is returned. In my XML I am setting the TextView width as WRAP_CONTENT.

How to get the width of the text view in PIXELS.

Thanks.

Comment: All the values that framework provides are in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for

[What is the difference between getWidth/Height() and getMeasuredWidth/Height() in Android SDK?](http://What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20getWidth/Height()%20and%20getMeasuredWidth/Height()%20in%20Android%20SDK?)

Answer (score -1):

```
txt_MyText.getWidth() // this will get you the view's width
txt_MyText.getHeight() // this will get you the view's height
```

the returned value will be in pixels